# Função `recode` (dplyr) não aceita intervalos numéricos

Tags: r

Considere o vetor:

```
x<-runif(30,20,100)
```

Gostaria de categorizar este vetor com a função `recode` do *package* `dplyr`. Os intervalos podem ser arbitrários. Por exemplo:

- de 20 a 50 = 1
- de 51 a 75 = 2
- de 76 a 100 = 3

Sei que posso lançar mão de outros pacotes e funções para executar esta ação. Mas, minha intenção é, especificamente, fazer isso com a função `recode` do `dplyr`. Já tentei fazer isto de muitas maneiras, mas até agora não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil de fazer isso é em base R com a função `findInterval`. A função `dplyr` apropriada será `case_when`, não `recode`. Aqui vão as duas maneiras.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1234)
x <- runif(30, 20, 100)

y1 <- case_when(
    20 <= x & x <= 50 ~ 1L,
    50 < x & x <= 75 ~ 2L,
    75 < x ~ 3L,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_
)

y2 <- findInterval(x, c(20, 50, 75))

identical(y1, y2)
#[1] TRUE
```

**Edição.**

Depois do [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/348764/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-recode-dplyr-n%c3%a3o-aceta-intervalos-num%c3%a9ricos/348774#comment701272_348774) do Marcus Nunes lembrei-me da função R base `cut`, que pode ser usada em conjunto com *pipes*, `%>%`. Como se pode ver pelo resultado, a saída é um objeto de classe `"factor"`.

```
x %>% cut(breaks = c(20, 50, 75, 100), labels = 1:3)
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 2 1 1 2 2 3 2 1 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 3 3
#[30] 1
#Levels: 1 2 3
```

Comment: Só pra complementar esta resposta, a seguinte informação está no help da versão 0.7.8 do `dplyr` (grifos meus): `All replacements **must be the same type**, and must have either length one or the same length as x`. Portanto, não dá pra alterar algo de numeric para factor usando `recode`.